# Why JVM work when there is not JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, java-home

```sh
$ env
...
```

When I try to print my shell environment on macOS, I find there is not a `JAVA_HOME`, but my JVM still works.

So I am very confused, I just want to understand how JVM finds the location of JDK when there is not indicated from shell `env`.

Then my JDK location is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk`, if I move out this folder, JVM will not work.

I know this is useless and very stupid. But I just want to fully understand how does this work, please help.

Comment: When you start a program, the operating system allows the program to find out where its executable was loaded from, this is just a basic function of the OS. The JVM does not use the JAVA_HOME environment variable, it's not necessary to set it for the JVM's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM does not require `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Once you install it in the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk` the internal `bin` directory is added to the `PATH` environment variable (or some other mechanism like `update-alternatives` is used to put `java` executable in the system `PATH`).

It's usually 3rd party tools that require JVM (e.g. Apache Maven or Tomcat) that use `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to find the installed JVM.